# Is there any way to use Auto Hot Keys on ubuntu?

Tags: wine

The link to their website is here: https://autohotkey.com/

Is there any way to install this on Ubuntu Gnome (or really any version)?

I have tried googling it but got no answer. Wine did not work for me.

I need to use this program and it's the only thing keeping me on windows.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What's its specific functional which you're missing on GNU/Linux? For writing things like `btw` → `by the way` you're looking for [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), which has by the way [great repository with ready-to-go combinations](https://github.com/kragen/xcompose). As for global shortcuts — you can add it through your window manager *(sorry, I was using KDE, I know it has in settings that; now I'm using AwesomeWM, and it configured with Lua; I'm sure Unity has something alike too)*.

Comment: I use it for basic mouse movements and remapping certain keys while playing games like runescape

Comment: Hard to say in general, but it looks like it is possible to just write scripts for window manager. But whatever, I just tried to run the app with wine-1.9.1, and it exits with «can't load icon» error. [Appdb mentions](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17738) some mystical AutohotkeysX port for GNU/Linux, but for some reason there's no information about it at all. I don't actually see any solution except for [reporting a bug](https://bugs.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I have already used AutoHotKeys on Windows, I doubt it can work fully on Linux (because It tries to control the desktop environment), however several Wine users reported good results, read this: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5173